# I have a source of numbers. Is there a way to estimate the probability for the given number to originate from it?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, random-variable, randomness

The source in question is some blackbox which output looks completely random to me, yey I haven't tested if for randomness quality. I don't exactly know insides of blackbox but can easily caputure it output 160bit integers, millions if necessary.

Comment: Capture its output and then model its distribution. After that you can test the probability of a given number originating from the distribution.

Comment: What if 20-th and 40-th bits of the numbers from distribution are always correlated (or something similar). How do I capture such stuff in the model without actually looking at the numbers myself and figuring out such peculiarity?

Comment: If you believe such effects are present you can try to model the output as a time series, for example using an [AR model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AR_model).

Comment: @MarcClaesen and what should be I learning: AR model or distribution of parameters of AR models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, first of all try to decide whether there is a reason to suspect an autoregressive generative process. You could do this, for example, by looking at correlation between outputs at varying delays. If you are modeling some kind of physical system you can use information about the structure. Since you mention it's a black-box I assume you have no such information.

If there is a reason to assume some kind of autoregressive process, I would focus on fitting an AR model. From a fitted model you can typically get confidence intervals on predictions which you can then use to assess whether a certain output falls within expectations. In case you get a terrible fit, (i) maybe there really is no underlying autoregressive process or (ii) you may need to use a nonlinear technique like SVM to adequately model the process.

Comment: I've never dealt with AR models. Any particular books or tutorials you can recommend?

Comment: An addition, I didn't quite understand  'by looking at correlation between outputs at varying delays'? Just try correlate n-th bit of single output with m-th?